# How can division be used to find the product of every value an input array except the value with a corresponding index

Tags: javascript

In an attempt to improve my general problem solving skills, I recently subscribed to [Daily Coding Problem](https://www.dailycodingproblem.com/). One of the challenges that came up has the following description:

> This problem was asked by Uber.
>
> Given an array of integers, return a new array such that each element
>   at index i of the new array is the product of all the numbers in the
>   original array except the one at i.
>
> For example, if our input was [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the expected output
>   would be [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]. If our input was [3, 2, 1], the
>   expected output would be [2, 3, 6].
>
> Follow-up: what if you can't use division?

I solved this particular challenge within minutes using the following function:

```
function solution(_input) {
  return _input.map((_number, _index, _list) => {
    return _list.reduce((_accumulator, _currentValue, _currentIndex) => {
      return _accumulator * ((_index !== _currentIndex) ? _currentValue : 1);
    }, 1);
  });
}
```

My function works, matching every expected output perfectly... But this makes me curious about the last line of the challenge.

How *could* division be used to solve this?

Comment: I presume you'd just calculate the total product of all elements, then map the array to be that product divided by each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6184972/steve) [alluded in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583898/is-this-the-best-way-to-solve-it-dailycodingproblem-challenge#comment90133292_51583898), you would:

- first find the product of all the elements in the array:

  ```
  const product = input.reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator * value, 1);
  ```
- then map the array to the product divided by each element.

  ```
  return input.map(value => product / value);
  ```

This reduces operational complexity from O(N<sup>2</sup>) to O(N) (if I'm not mistaken) because we are removing the nested loop.

```js
const func = input => {
    const product = input.reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator * value, 1);
    return input.map(value => product / value);
}

console.log(func([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```